# Display current version of Angular2 on UI

Tags: angular

I am working small Angular2 typescript application since last 2 months. As Angular2 moving from one version to another version like beta to RC1 > RC2 > RC3 > RC4, we want to show current version of Angular2 on UI.

Just like in .NET, we can do like this from code-

```
typeof(string).Assembly.ImageRuntimeVersion
```

Is there any option to display current Angular2 version on UI like - RC4 or 2.0.0-rc.4 ?

Answer (score 1):

Since **Angular 2.3.0-rc.0** you can do this (see [commit](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/16efb13dd19ae15d7ebcfa6e1abb267f66114f49)):

```
import { VERSION } from '@angular/core';

export class AppComponent { 
  constructor() {
    console.log(VERSION.full);
  }
}
```